# Query for pattern * ** ***, output from SQL without using dual

Tags: sql, oracle

This question was asked in an interview:

> Need to print the following pattern using SQL.  SQL should not have
> `dual` in the solution.

```
*
* *
* * *
```

I gave an answer as below:

```
select lpad(' ',level,'*') from dual
connect by level <= 3;
```

Another question was there with the same concept, to print my name vertically, like below.

```
M
A
N
A
S
I
```

How can we print these without `dual`?

Comment: This question has no valid answer and may lead to opinion-based solutions: system tables, `odci...list` constructor, `json_table`, `xmltable`, stored procedure with loop, manually created table, whatever

Comment: I don't believe the question is opinion based. There are many valid answers. OP is not asking for the **best** solution, just **a** solution. As stated, it was an interview question and interviewers typically throw in twists (like don't use `DUAL` in this case) to see what creative solutions you can come up with. If you were looking for an **optimal** solution, then it would likely be opinion-based and you would not have the restriction of not being able to use `DUAL`. All the answers below are valid answers because they result in the data OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, the first one is like a Code Golf question I answered ([Link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203062/triangular-code-triangular-output/203206#203206))

The only thing I can think of is to select from a system view instead of dual.

```sql
SELECT LPAD('*', ROWNUM, '*')
FROM all_objects ao
WHERE ROWNUM <= 3;
```

For the second one:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR('MANASI', ROWNUM, 1)
FROM all_objects ao
WHERE ROWNUM <= LENGTH('MANASI');
```

Answer (score 3):

One option to replace `DUAL` is to just select from any table/view that has at least one row and select `WHERE ROWNUM = 1`. In the query below I am using the `ALL_OBJECTS` view.

```sql
    SELECT LPAD ('*', LEVEL, '*')
          FROM (SELECT 1
                  FROM all_objects
                 WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;


   LPAD('*',LEVEL,'*')
______________________
*
**
***
```

For the second problem, you can use a similar solution about using any table/view with at least one row and select from that. Another cheeky solution is to use a `SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST` to just write out your name. Both queries below will give you the same result.

```sql
--Query 1
    SELECT SUBSTR (your_name, LEVEL, 1)     AS letters
      FROM (SELECT 'MANASI'     AS your_name
              FROM all_objects
             WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (your_name);

--Query 2 (Cheeky solution)
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE     AS letters
  FROM TABLE (sys.odcivarchar2list ('M',
                                    'A',
                                    'N',
                                    'A',
                                    'S',
                                    'I'));

--Result of both queries
   LETTERS
__________
M
A
N
A
S
I
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use any other table and restrict it to a single row:

```sql
WITH rsqfc ( value ) AS (
  SELECT '*' FROM all_tables WHERE ROWNUM = 1
UNION ALL
  SELECT value || ' *'
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  LENGTH(value) <= 5
)
SELECT value
FROM   rsqfc;
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT '*' AS value FROM all_tables WHERE ROWNUM = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '* *' FROM all_objects FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY)
UNION ALL
SELECT '* * *' FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS rn FROM all_tab_columns
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

or, restrict it to the number of rows you want:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR('* * *', 1, 2 * ROWNUM - 1) AS value
FROM   all_tables
WHERE  ROWNUM <= 3;
```

All output:

> | VALUE |
> | --- |
> | * |
> | * * |
> | * * * |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c6843161848d10f19dc4172b53711e9c)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [XQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery) expression in `xmltable()` as a row generator:

```
select rpad('*',rownum,'*')
from   xmltable('1 to 3');
```

```
select substr('MANASI',rownum,1)
from   xmltable('1 to 5'));
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e79921baa483a319f89a9f9560b56694)